# Hydra brute force error message

Tags: linux, hydra

```
hydra 190.13.132.90 -s 8081 -V -L /home/nicolas/Escritorio/USER -P /home/nicolas/Escritorio/passwords.txt http-post-form "/user=^USER^&password=^PASS^=Ingresar&culture=es-CL&mobile=0&clasica=1:F=Usuario inexistente:H=Cookie: stwa2={"lang":"es-CL"}"
Hydra v8.7-dev (c) 2017 by van Hauser/THC - Please do not use in military or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes.
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2018-04-29 14:34:51
[ERROR] the variables argument needs at least the strings ^USER^, ^PASS^, ^USER64^ or ^PASS64^: F=Usuario inexistente
```

Could anyone write the correct string to use in hydra please? I’m a noob using hydra :)

The username is Gonzalo Sepulveda.

The full URL of the login is:

http://190.13.132.90:8081/

Answer (score 4):

The `http-post-form` module requires three colon-separated arguments, like so:

```
/login.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:login failed
```

The "variables argument" where you supply the POST data with username and password placeholders (which I made bold) is the *second* argument. But you gave the POST data as the first argument which makes hydra think this is actually the path.

So, with your command hydra thinks...

```
/user=^USER^&password=^PASS^=Ingresar&culture=es-CL&mobile=0&clasica=1
```

...is the path and...

```
F=Usuario inexistente
```

are the POST parameters - which don't contain `^USER^` or `^PASS^` and are therefore invalid.

Comment: Could you write the correct string to use in hydra please? I’m a noob using hydra :)

Comment: @N1CR0N1X This isn't really a place where we just hand people the solution. Arminius has given you the reason why it's not working. It's up to him whether he hands you the answer to fixing it but we don't tend to do that here.